# How to require two PRIVATE keyholders to decrypt a document?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

Consider 3 entities **A**,**B** and **C**. I want **A** to be able to encrypt a document that can be decrypted only when keys of both **B** and **C** are combined. [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1048) question talks about a similar problem, but it uses AES.

In my usecase, I don't want the keys to be shared across the entities. There is one solution that was coming to my mind:
**A** encrypts the document (with RSA) first using public key of **B** and then public key of **C**. Then the document is decrypted using private key of C and then private key of B.

Is this approach feasible? Is there a better way?

Note: I tried doing this but got this error when I was doing encryption for the 2nd time: `Data must not be longer than 117 bytes`.

Comment: RSA is not used for encrypting bulk data, AES is. As a simple example, you can have A encrypt the document using AES keys k_B and k_C, as follows: AES(k_B, AES(k_C, data)). To this is appended RSA(pub_B, k_B) and RSA(pub_C, k_C). To decrypt, B must go first. B uses RSA to recover k_B, then uses AES with k_B to decrypt, leaving AES(k_C, data). Now give this to C and C can finish the decryption, using k_C to get all the way back to plaintext. This has the drawback that B has to go first. You can modify the scheme to eliminate this requirement.

Comment: What you want to do is known as "secret sharing" and has several approaches. Google is your friend.